# Python library for large scale convex optimization

Tags: python-3.x, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to find a library for convex optimization in python which can handle a large amount of variables and constraints.

My problem is in the form

```
min pT*q + |c|

lower bound < q < upper bound
lower bound < c < upper bound
A* q + B*c = b
lower bound < Rq < upper bound

from cvxopt.modeling import variable, op, sum
q = variable(numb_prod, 'q')
c = variable(numb_capacity, 'c')
prod_price = p.trans() * q

problem = op(sum(prod_price) + 1e-6*sum(abs(c)), [constraints])
problem.solve(format='sparse', solver='glpk', options={'glpk':{'msg_lev':'GLP_MSG_OFF'}})
```

Where p, b are vectors and A,B,R  are sparse matrices and q,c variables
For more info about the matrices one can look here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4018792/python-library-for-large-scale-convex-optimization?noredirect=1#comment8297384_4018792

Currently I'm having 108575 variables which is too large for cvxopt. I was hopping running an optimization which can handle the amount of variables in the millions...

Is there any library that can handle that? Or does one need to look into another language?

The problems seems to be inside cvxopt and not necessarily the solver
Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
> File "", line 489, in 
> q, c, total_cost_x, water_values, list_numb_of_capacity_variables = solution(demand, price_purchase_power, supply)
> File "", line 391, in solution
> test = problem.solve(format='sparse', solver='glpk', options={'glpk':{'msg_lev':'GLP_MSG_OFF'}})
> File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\modeling.py", line 2600, in solve
> t = self._inmatrixform(format)
> File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\modeling.py", line 2479, in _inmatrixform
> for v in variables: vmap[v] = x[vslc[v]]
> File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\modeling.py", line 240, in **getitem**
> return (+self).**getitem**(key)
> File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\modeling.py", line 931, in **getitem**
> f._linear = self._linear[l]
> File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\modeling.py", line 1385, in **getitem**
> for v,c in iter(self._coeff.items()):
> OverflowError: **Python int too large to convert to C long**

Comment: Maybe usefull things on here http://plato.asu.edu/sub/nlores.html  or http://leaves.shufe.edu.cn/static/docs/lc/manual.pdf

Comment: https://osqp.org/docs/index.html from the same list is also something I would like to throw the problem at

Comment: If |c| is absolute value, I think this is an LP.

Comment: yes its elementwise absolute value @ErwinKalvelagen

Answer (score 0):

This is really an LP (Linear Programming) problem:

```
  min sum(i, p(i)*q(i)) + sum(i,cabs(i))
  cabs(i) >= c(i)
  cabs(i) >= -c(i)
   other constraints
```

where `cabs` is an additional positive variable.

A model with 108,575 variables is not extremely large for an LP, so any good LP solver will do.